# mutate based on conditional sum in a group

Tags: r, dplyr

Say I have a dataframe like this:

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 20
df <- data.frame(ID = sample(1:5, n, replace = TRUE),
             Fac1 = sample(letters[1:5], n, replace = TRUE),
             Fac2 = sample(LETTERS[10:15], n, replace = TRUE),
             Val1 = sample(1:10, n, replace = TRUE)) %>% 
  arrange(ID) %>% group_by(ID,Fac1) %>% 
  summarise(Val1 = sum(Val1),Fac2 = first(Fac2)) %>%
  group_by(ID,Fac2) %>% 
  mutate(Val2 = sum(Val1))
df
   ID Fac1 Val1 Fac2 Val2
1   1    b    9    N    9
2   1    c    9    O    9
3   2    a    4    K    4
4   2    b   10    M   18
5   2    c    4    L    4
6   2    d    8    M   18
7   2    e   10    N   10
8   3    d   14    N   14
9   4    b    8    L   22
10  4    c   14    L   22
11  4    d    9    K    9
12  4    e    6    N    6
13  5    a   13    M   13
14  5    b    3    N    3
```

ID is a grouping variable. Rows with an Fac1 value of e should have the Fac2 value changed to be that same as the other row in the group where Fac1 is either b or c and the sum of Val 2 for the two rows if greater than 20. (I've simplified this to the point where you probably don't get why but just work with me).
This is what I have tried so far:

```
result <- df %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(Fac2 = case_when(
    Fac1 == "e" & 
      sum(Val2,ifelse(Fac1 %in% c("b","c"), Val2, 0)) > 20 ~
      ifelse(sum(Val2,ifelse(Fac1 %in% c("b","c"),Val2,0)) > 20,
             as.character(Fac2),
             NA_character_),
    TRUE ~ as.character(Fac2)
  ))
```

It doesn't work properly because it is summing the first value of Val2 in the group rather than only doing so when Fac1 is b or c.

Any ideas?

Adding desired outcome:

```
   ID Fac1 Val1 Fac2 Val2
1   1    b    9    N    9
2   1    c    9    O    9
3   2    a    4    K    4
4   2    b   10    M   18
5   2    c    4    L    4
6   2    d    8    M   18
7   2    e   10    M   10 **Changed to M b/c row 4 is M and 10 + 18 > 20
8   3    d   14    N   14
9   4    b    8    L   22
10  4    c   14    L   22
11  4    d    9    K    9
12  4    e    6    L    6 **Changed to L b/c row 10 is L and 6 + 22 > 20
13  5    a   13    M   13
14  5    b    3    N    3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the desired result with this code. I made a new column containing the result of the test for what value to replace Fac2 with, which wasn't entirely necessary but makes it more readable and debugable.
The key thing was to use `first(na.omit())` to get the value from a different row in the same group which met the condition.

```
result <- df %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(Max_bc_Val = ifelse(Val2 == max(ifelse(Fac1 %in% c("b","c"),
                                          Val2,0)),
                      ifelse(Fac1 %in% c("b","c"),
                             as.character(Fac2),NA),NA)) %>% 
  mutate(Fac2 = case_when(
    Fac1 == "e" ~ ifelse(is.na(first(na.omit(Max_bc_Val))),
                         NA_character_,
                         first(na.omit(Max_bc_Val))),
    TRUE ~ as.character(Fac2)))
```

This works but doesn't seem like the best solution. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a hard time following what you are wanting the values to be changed to.

But when I have multiple conditions or decisions that need to be made in a sequence, I use a loop and a series of if statements to go through the data frame. I prefer `while` loops, so that's what I'll use in the example.

```
counter <- 1
stopper <- nrow(df)
while (counter <= stopper) {

 fac1 <- df$Fac1[counter1]

 if (fac1 == 'e') {

  if ([INSERT NEXT CONDITION]) #Change whichever value your trying to change using the counter to reference the correct row.
  else #Change whichever value your trying to change using the counter to reference the correct row.

 }

counter <- counter + 1
}
```

For me, simplifying the code makes it a lot easier for me to keep track of what decisions are being made. It also allows for complex decisions that are difficult to get functions to work with.

Comment: Thanks but the condition is dependent on having a grouped data frame and that is the part I'm having trouble with not iterating over rows. I have added an example of the desired outcome. Hope that helps